Polya's Condition for characteristic functions
Im reading the proof of the Pólya's condition ( Theorem 4.3.1) in the book "Characteristic Functions , by Eugene Lukacs 2ed".
But i dont understand the following statament in the proof:
Asume that: (Because I did understand at this point)
$$p(x)=\frac{1}{\pi x}\int_0^\infty g(t)\sin(tx) dt $$
with $g(t)$ is non-increasing , non negative function,  for $t> 0$ and $$\lim_{t\to\infty} g(t) = 0 $$
Then $$p(x) = \frac{1}{\pi x} \int_{0}^{\pi/x} \left[ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^j g(t+\frac{j\pi}{x}) \right] \sin(tx) $$
I dont see the final equality , the serie is a approximation or just a smart rewriter of g???

Here is a detailed explanation: Remember that the variable of integration is $t$, and that $x$ is held constant. We replace the integral over $t\in(0,\infty)$ by the sum of integrals over $(0, \pi/x)$, $(\pi/x,2\pi/x)$, $(2\pi/x, 3\pi/x)$, etc:
$$
\int_{t=0}^\infty g(t)\sin(tx)dt= \sum_{j=0}^\infty\int_{t=j\pi/x}^{(j+1)\pi/x}g(t)\sin(tx)dt
$$
Make the change of variables $u:=t-j\pi/x$:
$$ 
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\int_{u=0}^{\pi/x}g\left(u+\frac{j\pi}x\right)\sin\left(ux+j\pi\right) du
$$Finally use the fact that $\sin(y+j\pi)=(-1)^j\sin(y)$ for every $y$ and integer $j$, and rename the dummy variable of integration from $u$ back to $t$.

Just a smart rewrite, based on the fact that $\sin (u)$ periodically changes sign as $u$ increases by $\pi$.
